# Is there a way to redirect a navigation request in a service worker?

Tags: javascript, http, service-worker

I have a special `/home` route that redirects different types of users to different places. This is also the `start_url` in my PWA manifest. However, if the user is offline (and so can't get the server `/home` route), rather than showing the offline page, I'd like to default to the home page ('/') and redirect there, or at least show that content (the '/' route is cached).

Here is a simplified version of the fetch listener:

```js
var staticRoutes = ['/'];

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    // If the request is for a static route try to fetch it; if can't, return the cached page
    staticRoutes.indexOf(new URL(event.request.url).pathname) > -1
      ? fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
          return caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response;
          })
      : caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
          return (
            response ||
            fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
              if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
                if (new URL(event.request.url).pathname === '/home') {
                  // What do I do hear to either:
                  // 1. redirect the user to the '/' route (letting it go through the service worker)
                  // 2. just display the content of the '/' route which is in the cache
                }
              }
            })
          )
        })
   )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve #2, you can put this in the block above:

```js
return caches.match(new Request('/'));
```

I had tried this but the service worker hadn't updated :face-palm: